# Simplifying a logical equivalence

Tags: propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra, equivalence-relations

http://www2.ift.ulaval.ca/~dadub100/cours/H09/22257/ntsLogique.pdf
If you look in Annex B, I am allowed to use all laws from chapter 3 and below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrCLK.jpg
This is the problem itself. I did not rewrite this. If there are any missing brackets, this is how the problem was given to me. I do not know how to prove this. I can't use a truth table, I have to simplify it to an existing theorem to prove its validity.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the author using $\equiv$ both as an operation in boolean algebra, and as a relation between boolean expressions?  Otherwise $\text{vrai} \equiv p \equiv p$ doesn't make sense to me.  But $\text{vrai} \equiv (p \leftrightarrow p)$ does make sense to me.

Comment: Never mind, I think I understand it now.  $\equiv$ is the operation throughout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT

Start out observing that:

$$S \equiv [\neg (Q \land R) \land (R \rightarrow Q)] \equiv S \Leftrightarrow$$

$$S \equiv S \equiv [\neg (Q \land R) \land (R \rightarrow Q)] \Leftrightarrow$$

$$vrai \equiv [\neg (Q \land R) \land (R \rightarrow Q)] \Leftrightarrow$$

$$[\neg (Q \land R) \land (R \rightarrow Q)]$$

Now do a DeMorgan and an Implication to simplify this even further, and you're almost there!

Comment: well damn...thank you very much!

Comment: well thanks to you, i was able to solve it @Bram28

Comment: @SamuelParent Yay!  Glad I could help! :) And since you're new .... you can accept my answer by clicking on the check mark next to it.